# How to add string in between a file in unix

Tags: unix, sed

File is

`AVAIL_CHECK_SECS=30` 
`# we need at least one server`
`if [ -z "$1" ]; then`
  `usage "Missing hostname parameter(s)"`
`fi`

Output should be

`AVAIL_CHECK_SECS=30` 
`# cache a copy of the agent jar for pushing to remote servers`
`# we need at least one server`
`if [ -z "$1" ]; then`
  `usage "Missing hostname parameter(s)"`
`fi`

I want to add a line between 2 lines i.e. # cache a copy of the agent jar for pushing to remote servers

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '1a\
# cache a copy of the agent jar for pushing to remote servers' File
```

This works by line number. You could replace 1 by `/^AVAIL_CHECK_SECS/`, or `1a` by `/# we need/i` to do it by matching patterns on the line before or after the position where the line should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1 {$0=$0 "\n# cache a copy of the agent jar for pushing to remote servers"} 1' file
AVAIL_CHECK_SECS=30
# cache a copy of the agent jar for pushing to remote servers
# we need at least one server
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
usage "Missing hostname parameter(s)"
fi
```